# Is there a way to create a function that given numbers 0-100 as input to only return certain numbers?

Tags: javascript, math

Is there a way i can create a function with only mathematical calculations in javascript that given numbers from 0 to 100 as input to only return 0/20/40/60/80/100?

If so, how?

For example, numbers raging from 0-19 => 0, 20-39 => 20, ..., 100 => 100

Thank you

Comment: Divide by 20, floor, and multiply by 20.

Comment: @AaditMShah also known as integer division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide by the the difference between each group, round the result down, and then multiply by the difference between each group:

```js
const nearest20 = (num) => Math.floor(num / 20)*20


console.log(nearest20(17))
console.log(nearest20(51))
console.log(nearest20(100))
console.log(nearest20(0))
console.log(nearest20(22))
console.log(nearest20(70))
console.log(nearest20(89))
console.log(nearest20(24))
```

Answer (score 1):

The sortest way is probably subtracting the modulus 20 from the number.

```js
const trunc20 = (n) => n-n%20;

console.log(trunc20(17))
console.log(trunc20(51.8))
console.log(trunc20(100))
console.log(trunc20(0))
console.log(trunc20(22))
console.log(trunc20(70))
console.log(trunc20(89))
console.log(trunc20(24))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very confusing. You should always let people of this community know what you've already tried. Anyway, as per my understanding, you can do the required in a following way:

```
const transformNumbers = (number) => {
  let to_be_returned;
  to_be_returned = Math.floor(number/20)*20 ;
  return to_be_returned;
}

let data = transformNumbers(99); 
console.log(data); // outputs 80
```